# Can hard gold be selectively used on a PCB in the center of the board?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I have charging pads at the center of the device which makes repeated contact with a pogo pin. I'm concerned an ENIG pad may wear out over time as the user clicks it on and off the charger.

Can hard gold can be used to selectively plate this pad at the center of the board?
I've only seen hard gold be partially used on a PCB when it's at the board edge, for example in PCIE fingers.

Would hard gold have a higher chance of corrosion if a user sweats onto the pads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask a fab -- that's really your go-to location for any questions about fab.  If they can do it, I mean, that's all you need to know.  Capabilities vary from shop to shop, of course, so you may have to ask around a few places to see what, or why.

There is one general reason, however: heavy gold is electroplated.  The traces must be shorted together at some point, so that an electrical connection can be made.

Edge fingers are made by extending the board, where the fingers are shorted together, and the whole end is dipped and plated.  After, the shorting tab is milled off, and the edges chamfered for easy insertion.

In the middle of the board, you'll probably need to add a shorting feature somewhere, somehow, to allow electrical conduction.  Maybe this is milled out by the fab, maybe you can arrange some way to connect them externally (assemble with one connector, plug it in to the bath?), but the more specialized it gets, the more they're going to charge for it.

There is another route:

Have you considered pogo targets, such as these?
[Contacts, Spring Loaded (Pogo Pins), and Pressure | Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/j55dt343)

Comment: Great info, I wasn't aware of how hard gold was fabricated. The fact that those SMD pogo targets exist makes me believe other people have run into wear issues on HASL/ENIG!

Comment: Well, ENIG is very poor wearing indeed, it's extremely thin layers.  That said, I'm a bit surprised the targets aren't available in heavier plating (at least, among what appears in that cursory query).  HASL, is basically just tin plating, which is fine for connector purposes, but must be paired with tin-plated contacts, and maybe that's harder to assure with pogo pins, or less contact wiping occurs.